# CUPTI: Add more events to the trace

Tags: cuda

I am trying to trace 3 counters in a CUDA program as follows:

```
void *
sampling_func(void *arg)
{
  CUptiResult cuptiErr;
  CUpti_EventGroup eventGroup;
  CUpti_EventID gldrID, gldhitID, gldmissID; //eventId;
  size_t bytesRead;
  uint64_t eventVal;

  cuptiErr = cuptiSetEventCollectionMode(context,
                                         CUPTI_EVENT_COLLECTION_MODE_CONTINUOUS);
  CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiSetEventCollectionMode");

  cuptiErr = cuptiEventGroupCreate(context, &eventGroup, 0);
  CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGroupCreate");

  cuptiErr = cuptiEventGetIdFromName(device, gld_request, &gldrID); //"gld_request"
  CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGetIdFromName");

  cuptiErr = cuptiEventGetIdFromName(device, l1_gld_hit, &gldhitID); //"l1_global_load_hit"
  CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGetIdFromName");

  cuptiErr = cuptiEventGetIdFromName(device, l1_gld_miss, &gldmissID); //"l1_global_load_miss"
  CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGetIdFromName");

  cuptiErr = cuptiEventGroupAddEvent(eventGroup, gldrID);
  CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGroupAddEvent");

  cuptiErr = cuptiEventGroupAddEvent(eventGroup, gldhitID);
  CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGroupAddEvent");

  cuptiErr = cuptiEventGroupAddEvent(eventGroup, gldmissID);
  CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGroupAddEvent");

  cuptiErr = cuptiEventGroupEnable(eventGroup);
  CHECK_CUPTI_ERROR(cuptiErr, "cuptiEventGroupEnable");
```

Although when at run time, I get following error:

```
:Error CUPTI_ERROR_INVALID_EVENT_ID for CUPTI API function 'cuptiEventGroupAddEvent'.
```

This points to the send call to `cuptiEventGroupAddEvent` for `gldhitID`. I tried various combinations and it seems I cannot add more counters at the same time, which I believe should not be the case. Also all these counters work one at a time well.

I am using CUDA compute compatibility 2.0 device.

Any suggestions? What am I doing wrong?

BTW, I am following code at this [link](https://github.com/tbrand/MobileCUDA/blob/master/src/cupti2.c).

Comment: I believe the problem lies with the argument to `sampling_func` but I cannot identify it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUPTI provides the `cuptiEventGroupSetsCreate()` API for precisely this purpose. You can pass in an array of event IDs, and you get event group sets as output.

An event group set is a collection of event groups, each of which can be profiled in a single pass. This way, you don't have to worry about manually sorting the event IDs into separate event groups.

Here's a short snippet to give you a general idea of how to use event group sets:

```
CUpti_EventID eventIds[3];
cuptiEventGetIdFromName(device, "name_of_event_0", &eventIds[0]);
cuptiEventGetIdFromName(device, "name_of_event_1", &eventIds[1]);
cuptiEventGetIdFromName(device, "name_of_event_2", &eventIds[2]);

CUpti_EventGroupSets *sets = NULL;
cuptiEventGroupSetsCreate(context, sizeof(eventIds), eventIds, &sets);

// Iterate over each set
for (int i = 0; i < sets->numSets; i++) {
    // Iterate over each event group in the set
    for (int j = 0; j < sets->sets[i].numEventGroups; j++) {
        // Enable the event group
        cuptiEventGroupEnable(sets->sets[i].eventGroups[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so problem is with the profile counters I am looking into:

"gld_request" and, "l1_global_load_hit" and l1_global_load_miss" belong to different 'domains'. Unfortunately, the CUDA error was not very specific.

Anyway, the problem went away once I created two separate eventGroups for each domain.

Comment: CUPTI provides the `cuptiEventGroupSetsCreate()` API for precisely this purpose. You can pass in an array of event IDs, and you get an event group set as output.

An event group set is a collection of event groups, each of which can be profiled in a single pass. This way, you don't have to worry about manually sorting the event IDs into separate event groups.

Comment: Oh, I never looked into that. I like stackoverflow points, but your answer is the appropriate one. Post it as a separate answer and I will accept that. If possible please be more descriptive as it might help future readers. CUPTI documentation is a bit difficult to follow.

Comment: Also, I am looking into the CUDA profiler now. Is it okay if I tag you in future questions?

Comment: Posted as an answer. As for your profiler questions, I'll be keeping an eye on the questions tagged with the CUDA tag, so I will try and answer them wherever possible.